# What's the formula for Block?

Tags: trimps

There are two different ways to increase Block, that I know of, at least:

- Gyms give 4 (6 after upgrade) block per building.
- Trainers increase block by 20% (25% after the one upgrade I've found)

Gyms are pretty straightfoward.  4/6 per building, per trimp.

The trouble comes when you start adding in trainers; my calculations aren't matching, so it's hard to figure out which option is more efficient for me at any particular point.

For example, I currently have 15 gyms, 17 trainers, and 7 trimps fighting.  My (extremely straightforward math) says I should have:

15*6*(17*.25) = 382 block per trimp.  Multiply that by 7, and I get 2677.5.  But...I actually have 3307 Block.  What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The formula, according to [game's script](http://trimps.github.io/main.js?8) is `game.global.soldierCurrentBlock = Math.floor((game.global.block * (game.jobs.Trainer.owned * (game.jobs.Trainer.modifier / 100)) + game.global.block) * trimpsFighting);`

Breakdown of the code:
`game.global.block` = number of gyms * block per gym
`game.jobs.Train.owned` = number of trainers
`(game.jobs.Trainer.modifier/100)` = percentage of trainer block increase, i.e if it's 25% then put 0.25 here
`trimpsFighting` = the number of trimps fighting

Comment: I couldn't find what `game.global.block` is in the code though.

Comment: I found `game.global.block` in [this](http://trimps.github.io/config.js?8), but it's 0 by default. It seems that it's the total block from Gym.

Comment: I just put in my numbers and it matches perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

The formula without Heirlooms is:

```
trainer_percentage = 100*(0.2 + 0.05*traintacular)
block_per_gym = 6*(1.04 + gymystic*0.01)^gyms

block = trimps*(shield_base*shield_lvl + gyms*block_per_gym)*(1 + trainers*trainer_percentage/100)
```

---

### Example

Let's say I have 5298 trimps: `trimps = 5298`;

[image: Trimps]

My shield is level 3 and has a base block of 6.09e4: `shield_lvl = 3` and `shield_base = 6.09e4`;

[image: Shield]

I have 107 gyms which give 9571 block each: `gyms = 109` and `block_per_gym = 9571`;

[image: Gyms]

And I have 170 trainers giving +55% block each: `trainers = 174` and `trainer_percentage = 55`;

[image: Trainers]

Then my total block is given by:

```
block = trimps*(shield_base*shield_lvl + gyms*block_per_gym)*(1 + trainers*trainer_percentage/100)
block = 5298*(6.09e4*3 + 109*9571)*(1 + 174*55/100)
```

Which gives 6.28069e+11.

[image: Block]